# Debugging without logs and tools?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I was browsing into raspberry pi source code at git and realized they don't have any logs and printf in the source. Is there any other debugging techniques out apart from logging, debugging tools (gdb, dbx) which are used in such scenarios?

Comment: Which part of the source code? The raspberry pi kernel is a Linux fork and therefore has tons of logging and debugging utilities.

Comment: @nickelpro I am not saying "pi" don't have any logging utilities, I mentioned "pi" just for example sake, all I was asking an approach or methodology apart from standard practices, for you reference I was browsing  "https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-4.19.y/block" folder. -thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For kernel level debugging there is plenty of logging and hooking debuggers (usually via serial link), especially for brand new code. Excessive logging is usually stripped when the code is mature and patches are being prepared for submission to the kernel.

Additionally, a very common method of debugging or just understanding kernel code is with [function tracing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ftrace). This is similar to a debug build, GCC adds a function call to every function in the kernel, `mcount()`. For a typical ftrace kernel build, `mcount()` will compile to a NOP which will be dynamically replaced at runtime via ftrace utilities.

You can read more about the design of ftrace in the kernel docs [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.18/trace/ftrace-design.html). You can learn more about the information provided by ftrace [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.18/trace/ftrace.html), but suffice to say it's extensive.